# Codeigniter image tag - errors occurring

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, image

I use codeigniter as my framework and testing a site on a localhost. At the moment I am using img tags as the following:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/images/image.png" class="home"/>
```

This shows the image- great, but when validating html I get the following message:

"Character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
This message may appear in several cases:

- You should escape it as &lt
- You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&", which is always safe.
- Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.

I have also tried the Codeigniter html helper of the img tag array and when I do this it doesn't show the image and any code underneath this line does not show.

Any suggestions to mark this code better or a way of passing the validation checks as I like to be 100% pass rate.

Comment: I think the problem could be something else. Just remove the tag and run the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please remove / at the end of the

```
base_url()
```

base_user function by default provides / at the end 
use this way

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/image.png" class="home"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have removed the "/" and validates. I also tried the site url and this also works. Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using site_url

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url('/assets/images/image.png');?>" class="home"/>
```